# Incomplete type error in C while using structures

Tags: c, header, linker, structure

Hello i encoutnered a problem.
Here is my header file with structure definition and a method prototype.

```
typedef struct SymbolTable
{
     ...some elements
}ST;

extern struct ST STable;
void Symbol_Put(ST *S, char* sym);
```

In my c program i use:

```
#include "myheader.h"
struct ST STable;
```

and in the method i am using methods from header file.

```
...body of the method...
int id = Symbol_Put(STable,sym_name);
```

Unfortuneately i am getting this error:

```
‘STable’ has an incomplete type
  int s = Symbol_Put(STable,sym_name)
```

I don't understand what is wrong. I would be grateful for pointing me where i made a mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Why the `typedef` is you use the `struct` tag anyway?

Comment: incorrect syntax for this line: `extern struct ST STable;`  Due to the typedef, the line should be either: `extern ST STable;` or `extern struct SymbolTable STable;`.  Note: when using most debuggers, using the tag name 'SymbolTable' will result in the debugger displaying all the contained fields while using the typedef name: `ST` will make display of the individual fields very difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is no `struct ST` in your code. There's only `struct SymbolTable` and `ST`.

   Change the declaration to

   ```
   extern ST STable;
   ```

   and the definition to

   ```
   ST STable;
   ```
2. `Symbol_Put` expects a pointer as the first argument but you pass a `ST`. Replace the invocations by

   ```
   int id = Symbol_Put(&STable,sym_name);
   ```

Comment: hmm, now i am getting this error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘Symbol_Put’

Comment: @Dago Yes, `Symbol_Put` expects a pointer. That's pretty obvious, IMHO. Try something on your own beforehand!